# Сделать в слове первую букву заглавной

Tags: javascript

Предположим, что у вас есть объект с фамилией «иВанов» именем «ивАН» и отчеством «иваНОВИЧ». Ваш код при сборке поля ФИО должен преобразовать данные выше в «Иванов Иван Иванович»

```
 const User = { Sername: 'Иванов', Name: 'Иван', SecondName: 'Иванович' };
 const User1 = { Sername: 'Петров', Name: 'Семен', SecondName: 'Федорович'};
 const User2 = { Sername: 'Абашкин', Name: 'Ильдар', SecondName: 'Янович' };
 const User3 = { Sername: 'Цветков', Name: 'Петр', SecondName: 'Васильевич' };
 const User4 = { Sername: 'Константинов', Name: 'Анатолий', SecondName: 'Александрович' };
 const User5=[User, User1, User2, User3, User4];

for (let i=0; i<User5.length; i++){
     User5[i].FIO= User5[i].Sername.toUpperCase()+.slice(1)+''+User5[i].Name[0].toUpperCase()+' '+User5[i].SecondName[0].toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Вот вы описали "что нужно". И что вы ждёте? Что люди подключаться к вашему мозгу и узнают в чём у вас проблема и в чём вопрос?

Comment: Ну предположим. Здорово правда? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

```js
const toFormatName = string => {
    return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.toLowerCase().slice(1);
}

const people = [
  { Surname: 'иваНов', Name: 'ивАн', SecondName: 'иванОвич' },
  { Surname: 'петроВ', Name: 'семУн', SecondName: 'федоРович'},
  { Surname: 'абашкиН', Name: 'ильдАр', SecondName: 'яноВич' },
  { Surname: 'цвеТков', Name: 'петР', SecondName: 'васильевИЯ' },
  { Surname: 'консТАнтинов', Name: 'пнатолий', SecondName: 'алексанДРОвич' }
];

for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  let { Surname, Name, SecondName } = people[i];
  Surname = toFormatName(Surname);
  Name = toFormatName(Name);
  SecondName = toFormatName(SecondName);
  people[i] = { Surname, Name, SecondName };
}

console.log(people)
```

Сделал функцию которая берет строку, получает первый символ и переводит в заглавную букву, затем берет всю строку переводит в маленькие буквы, обрезает первый символ и объединяет с тем увеличенным первым символом.

Объединил всех людей в нормальный массив, прохожу циклом по нему, получаю все данные, прокидываю их в функцию и перезаписываю запись о человеке.

Comment: можете помочь еще с одной задачей: Проверить являются ли все пользователи в массиве совершеннолетними. const User = { Sername: 'Иванов', Name: 'Иван', SecondName: 'Иванович', Age: 18,Gender:'Мужчина', Yearofbirth:2005};
const User1 = { Sername: 'Петров', Name: 'Семен', SecondName: 'Федорович', Age: 35,Gender:'Мужчина', Yearofbirth:1988};
const User2 = { Sername: 'Абашкин', Name: 'Ильдар', SecondName: 'Янович',  Age: 12,Gender:'Мужчина', const User5=[ User,User1, User2, User3];